# How to configure Keycloak to work with Guacamole's OpenID plugin?

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, guacamole

I'm trying to setup Apache Guacamole with KeyCloak as OpenID Connect Authorization Server.

Guacamole is redirecting me to KeyCloak, I can Log in with my user I created on KeyCloak and I get redirected back to Guacamole, but there it says that my token is invalid

```
08:08:11.477 [http-nio-4432-exec-7] INFO  o.a.g.a.o.t.TokenValidationService - Rejected invalid OpenID token: Unable to process JOSE object (cause: org.jose4j.lang.UnresolvableKeyException: Unable to find a suitable verification key for JWS w/ header {"alg":"RS256","typ" : "JWT","kid" : "8ZNpgh_vnmG0HMMNYdOz1lw4ECoWxmsiUGte1mJfvyI"} due to an unexpected exception (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty) while obtaining or using keys from JWKS endpoint at https://172.16.47.229:12345/auth/realms/Guacamole-test/protocol/openid-connect/certs): JsonWebSignature{"alg":"RS256","typ" : "JWT","kid" : "8ZNpgh_vnmG0HMMNYdOz1lw4ECoWxmsiUGte1mJfvyI"}->eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI4Wk5wZ2hfdm5tRzBITU1OWWRPejFsdzRFQ29XeG1zaVVHdGUxbUpmdnlJIn0.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.eOhkDqcgfdJnO12PRDqLIHACRNVdVHoSDFjThHWc6Ug1gdoz9t_T2K7F_B6dJSbNygAJrGvc5BVRx9XCJH1fVFSYhpXVqCO0jrHm0XJKhw_kBce4x3ZluGAtktx614j9qFzUwZHXOkFAUGPtyPQKuRTfdzHqQUILLJhVdSRPmou40rX31-l7VwqWZk_Yp1JCdQsA61XvJcQrU_aiKivZFaDGiY5GrnpL8zcEwJcFemptVoGKrG63O_LjxDCxhLpO1C1fi8GjngMSfco9aAp4AaGpHWy8ofJAu-TWbLGf-UPLUhC3lf903-Q_BU3eehYxtMyN1eet0HeGm0x_gV_wvA
```

In KeyCloak I created a Client as follows:

[image: KeyCloak Configuration]

(Will change the Valid Redirect URI`s once I have it working)

And my guacamole.properites look like this:

```
guacd-port: 4822
guacd-hostname: localhost

# OpenID Connect Properties
openid-authorization-endpoint: https://172.16.47.229:12345/auth/realms/Guacamole-test/protocol/openid-connect/auth
openid-jwks-endpoint: https://172.16.47.229:12345/auth/realms/Guacamole-test/protocol/openid-connect/certs
openid-issuer: https://172.16.47.229:12345/auth/realms/Guacamole-test
openid-client-id: Guacamole
openid-redirect-uri: http://172.16.47.229:4432/guacamole/

# Postgresql Properties
postgresql-hostname: 172.16.47.229
postgresql-port: 4444
postgresql-database: guacamoledb
postgresql-username: guacamoleuser
postgresql-password: test
```

What do I have to change for guacamole to accept the token?

Update: I found the configuration to be working, if I use KeyCloak with HTTP instead of HTTPS, but that is not desirable. I have now also configured Guacamole, or more precisely the tomcat that's hosting guacamole, to use https, but I still can not get it to work (without having to use HTTP for KeyCloak).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've caught the same issue. Most probably you just have to provide valid SSL certificate for your IdP (Keycloak).

Possible workaround was found here: [How to configure Keycloak to work with Guacamole's OpenID plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64335904/how-to-configure-keycloak-to-work-with-guacamoles-openid-plugin).

I've re-compiled `guacamole-auth-openid` extension with this change:

```
diff --git a/extensions/guacamole-auth-openid/src/main/java/org/apache/guacamole/auth/openid/token/TokenValidationService.java b/extensions/guacamole-auth-openid/src/main/java/org/apache/guacamole/auth/openid/token/TokenValidationService.java
index 5efb09dab..27d818ee5 100644
--- a/extensions/guacamole-auth-openid/src/main/java/org/apache/guacamole/auth/openid/token/TokenValidationService.java
+++ b/extensions/guacamole-auth-openid/src/main/java/org/apache/guacamole/auth/openid/token/TokenValidationService.java
@@ -79,6 +79,7 @@ public class TokenValidationService {
 
         // Create JWT consumer for validating received token
         JwtConsumer jwtConsumer = new JwtConsumerBuilder()
+               .setSkipSignatureVerification()
                 .setRequireExpirationTime()
                 .setMaxFutureValidityInMinutes(confService.getMaxTokenValidity())
                 .setAllowedClockSkewInSeconds(confService.getAllowedClockSkew())
```

And this solved the issue. Don't think it's applicable for production needs but in production self-signed certificates should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

With Guacamole 1.4.0 and Keycloak 15.0.2 I fixed the HTTPS issue by mounting a custom `cacerts` keystore in the the Guacamole container. This custom keystore is just the OpenJDK 8 `cacerts` with Let's Encrypt CA bundle https://letsencrypt.org/certs/isrgrootx1.pem imported. Because my Keycloak and Guacamole instance use Let's Encrypt certificates.

On the host I had OpenJDK 8 installed. So Docker mount was

```
/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts:/usr/local/openjdk-8/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```